# What can be said about $a^{\lfloor \log_ab \rfloor}$?

Tags: logarithms

I am looking for formulas similar to classical logarithmic identities:
$$a^{\log_ab}=b$$
$$a^{\log_cb}=b^{\log_ca}$$

involving floor or ceiling functions.

I need to evaluate the following expressions:

**$$a^{\lfloor \log_ab \rfloor}$$
$$a^{\lceil \log_ab \rceil}$$**

Is it possible to assert something about the last two expressions?

Comment: could invoke monotonicity of exponential function, can't really think of anything else

Comment: Interesting to make a contour plot  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ContourPlot%5Ba%5EFloor%5BLog%5Bb%5D%2FLog%5Ba%5D%5D%2C+%7Ba%2C+1%2C+1000%7D%2C+%7Bb%2C+1%2C+1000%7D%5D

Comment: Assuming that $~b \geq a,~$ consider placing $~b~$ somewhere between two of the terms of the sequence $~a^1, ~a^2, ~a^3, ~a^4, ~\cdots.$

Answer (score 0):

As the comment say the inequalities based on monotonicity seems the best we can conclude. We have
$$\log_ab-1<\lfloor\log_ab\rfloor\le\log_ab,$$
and since the function $x\mapsto\log_ax$ is continuous this inequality cannot be sharpened. Indeed if $b=a^n$ for some integer $n$ we have the equality on the right, and $b$ can be arbitrarily close to some integer power of $a$ from the left so that $\lfloor\log_ab\rfloor$ is arbitrarily close to the lower bound. Again since the function $x\mapsto a^x$ is continuous the best we can conclude is
$$b/a<\lfloor\log_ab\rfloor\le b$$
(if $a>1$) or
$$b\le\lfloor\log_ab\rfloor<b/a$$
(if $0<a<1$).